# Authenticating to a GCP HTTP Cloud Function with a Firebase ID Token doesn't work?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, jwt

**I know this is a duplicate question, but I haven't seen anyone present a swift and python implementation. In addition, i've tried everything listed in the other questions, and nothing seems to work**

**Environments and Conditions:**

- Calling the http Cloud Function from an iOS app after I get the ID
  token (with the ID token)
- Written in Swift
- The Cloud Function is written in Python
- I cannot use HTTP callables as they are not deployable via the current terraform infrastructure in place (at least not that I know of, but would be open to any ideas)

**Problem:**

So, I was under the assumption that including the Firebase ID token of a Firebase user inside of the Authorization header works ,but it hasn't been for me even with a force refresh. I get a 403 status response with message: `The access token could not be verified`. That being said, if I go into CLI and get the id token of my actual gcp user account via: `gcloud auth print-identity-token` then replace the header with said token, I am verified.

**Swift Request Code (excuse the lack of convention, this is just POCing before I make a real implementation):**

```
guard let user = Auth.auth(app: authAppToUse).currentUser else { fatalError("SearchMySQL -> user: \(String(describing: Auth.auth(app: authAppToUse).currentUser))") }
user.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true) { (idToken, err) in
    if err != nil{
        fatalError("SearchMySQL -> user.getIDToken -> err: \(String(describing: err))")
    }

    guard let guardedIdToken = idToken else { fatalError("SearchMySQL -> guardedIdToken: \(String(describing: idToken))") }
    let rawJSON = [
        "data" : [
            "table": table,
            "search_by": searchBy,
            "search_by_value": searchByValue
        ]
    ]

    guard let guardedJSON = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: rawJSON, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
        return
    }

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://us-east1-fresh-customer-dev-ocean.cloudfunctions.net/mysql_search") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.addValue("Bearer \(idToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = guardedJSON

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print(err?.localizedDescription)
            fatalError("SearchMySQL -> URLSession.shared.dataTask -> err: \(String(describing: err))")
        }
        guard let guardedData = data else {
              return
        }

        print(idToken)
        print(response.debugDescription)

        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: guardedData, options: .allowFragments)
        print(json)

        completion(data)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Python Cloud Function:**

```
def main(request):
    """Background Http Triggered Cloud Function for ********.
    Validates authentication with Firebase ID token

    Returns:
        ********.main(payload): http response code and data payload (or message)
    """

    # validate request authorization
    if not request.headers.get('Authorization'):
        log.fatal('No Authorization Token provided')
        return {'message': 'No Authorization Token provided'}, 400
    try:
        id_token = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
    except (ValueError, InvalidIdTokenError, ExpiredIdTokenError, RevokedIdTokenError, CertificateFetchError) as e:
        log.fatal(f'Authorization `id_token` error: {e}')
        return {'message':f'Authorization `id_token` error: {e}'}, 400

    data_payload = request.get_json(force=True)

    if not data_payload.table:
        log.fatal('Payload missing table field.')
        return {'message': 'Payload missing table field'}, 422

    if not data_payload.search_by:
        log.fatal('Payload missing search_by field.')
        return {'message': 'Payload missing search_by field'}, 422
    
    return ********.main(data_payload)
```

**Ideas/Questions:**

1. Aren't Firebase ID tokens equivalent to Google ID Tokens?
2. Could there be an iAM permission issue for the (auto generated)
   firebase service account?
3. Do I need to also add any of the plist values to the idtoken when
   sending it over in the header?
4. Could it be something with the rules of my cloud function?
5. Am I missing something, or is this intended/expected behavior? With
   http callables being regular http functions but with protocols
   packaged to facilitate, I would think that this is a relatively easy
   implementation....
6. I've thought of the route of using an admin function to send a
   message to the mobile instance that needs a google id token during
   login, but the overhead and latency would result in issues.

Comment: Have you tried with Postman? I do think the Id token part is correct.

Comment: I have not tried with Postman. 
I just edited the member roles to "allUsers" and it worked but "allAuthenticatedUsers" did not. Does this have anything to do with it? So if this is the only way for it to work, then firebase id tokens are technically not equivalent to (or usable as) gcp id tokens

Comment: To look into your scenario, are you using any documentation to do this?

Comment: Yeah the official gcp docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference

Comment: To look further into this scenario, can you please provide the detailed log for the access token that cannot be verified, specifically the 403?

Comment: I went another way with this solution anyway after I remembered that http responses are limited to 10MB uncompressed. BUT, I concluded (for future reference) that allUsers DOES have to be enabled for cloud invoker role. After deploying a few http callable functions in a dev environment, it seems all are auto giving allUsers cloud invoker role so it's to be more of a gcs requirement than anything else. Otherwise cloud endpoints could be a nice proxy to go in between. Thoughts?

Comment: To find the information you need, do you have any specific questions? Maybe a new Stackoverflow question would be appropriate.

Comment: Eh the solution I have at hand seems scalable and reliable for now. I'm also not a dedicated backend guy so i'll leave that for the future. Thank you!